# If $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $\sum a_n$ diverges. Then for each increasing subsequence $(n_k)\subset\mathbb{N},\sum n_k(a_{n_k}-a_{n_{k+1}})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

I had a proposition:

> Suppose $\ (a_n)_n\ $ is a positive, decreasing real sequence such
> that $\ \displaystyle \sum_n a_n\ $ diverges. Then for **any** increasing
> subsequence $\ (n_k)_k\ \subset \mathbb{N},\  S: = n_1 a_{n_1} +
>  \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (n_k - n_{k-1}) a_{n_k} =
>  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} n_k (a_{n_k} - a_{n_{k+1} })\ $ diverges.

The proposition if true would help prove some other propositions I am working on.

However, I think I have found a counter-example. But I would like to check and confirm my calculations, as well as welcome any other "straightforward/ easier" counter-examples, although I didn't find any.

My counter-example is $\ a_n = \frac{1}{n\log n}\ $ and $\ n_k = 2^{2^k}.$ Then,

$$\ S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ 2^{2^k}\left( \frac{1}{ 2^{2^k} \log\left( 2^{2^k} \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ 2^{2^{k+1}} \log\left( 2^{2^{k+1}} \right) } \right) $$

$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{ \log\left( 2^{2^k} \right) } - \frac{ 2^{2^k} }{ 2^{2^{k+1}} \log\left( 2^{2^{k+1}} \right) }  $$

$$ \overset{*}{=} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{ \log\left( 2^{2^k} \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ 2^{2^k} \log\left( 2^{2^{k+1}} \right) }  $$

$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ \frac{1}{ 2^k \log\left( 2 \right) } - \frac{ 1 }{ 2^{2^k} 2^{k+1} \log2 }  $$

$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ \frac{ 1 }{ 2^k \log 2} \left( 1 - \frac{ 1 }{ 2\cdot 2^{2^k} } \right) $$

$$ < \frac{1}{\log 2}\ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ \frac{ 1 }{ 2^k} $$

which clearly converges.

$$ (*)\ \frac{ 2^{2^k} }{ 2^{2^{k+1} } } = 2^{ 2^k } \cdot 2^{ - 2^{k + 1} } = 2^{ 2^k (1-2) } = 2^{ -2^k} = \frac{ 1 }{ 2^ {2^k}.} $$

Assuming this is all correct, this also helps to give a counter-example to the following proposition:

> If $\ (a_n)_n,\ (b_n)_n,\ $ are positive decreasing sequences such
> that $\ \displaystyle\sum a_n\ $ converges and $\ \displaystyle\sum b_n\ $ diverges, then $\
>  \frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0.\ $

Then the following is a counter-example:

$$b_n = \frac{1}{n\log n},$$

$$\text{ For each } k\in\mathbb{N},\ a_n = \frac{ 1 }{ 2^{2^{k+1}} \log\left( 2^{2^{k+1}} \right) } \text{ if }\ 2^{2^k} < n\leq 2^{2^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Your counterexample seems correct to me. As for your proposition, it would seem like there is a [slightly weaker version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Schl%C3%B6milch's_Generalization) that is this time true. Just in case that helps you with what you are working on.

Comment: If you replace $n_k(a_{n_k}-a_{n_{k+1}})$ with $n_{k+1}(a_{n_k}-a_{n_{k+1}})$ the series should diverge.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, that's because, since $\ (a_n)_n\ $ is positive and decreasing, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} n_{k+1} (a_{n_k} - a_{n_{k+1} }) = n_2 a_{n_1} +
 \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (n_{k+1} - n_{k}) a_{n_k} \geq n_2 a_{n_1} +
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{n_2 + k},\ $$ which diverges. So without trying to sound rude, compared to the question, that's a relatively trivial statement.